# Why generic interfaces are not co/contravariant by default?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

For example `IEnumerable<T>` interface:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

In this interface the generic type is used only as a return type of interface method and not used as a type of method arguments thus it can be covariant. Giving this, can't compiler theoretically infer the variance from the interface? If it can, why does C# requires us to set co/contravariance keywords explicitly.

**Update**: As Jon Skeet mentioned this question can be spited into sub-questions:

1. **Can** compiler infer generic type's co/contravariance by how it is used inside current generic type and all it's base types?

   For example.. How many generic interface parameters from .NET Framework 4.0 can be marked co/contravariant automatically without any ambiguity? About 70%, 80%, 90% or 100%?
2. If it can, **should** it apply co/contravariance to generic types by default? At least to those types which it is capable to analyze and infer co/contravariance from the type usage.

Comment: Excellent question. I anticipated your question in 2007 when we were designing this feature. Which is why I wrote an article answering it back then: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/29/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-seven-why-do-we-need-a-syntax-at-all.aspx

Comment: There are some excellent answers below regarding why this isn't automatic. I just wanted to add that ReSharper *will* suggest co/contra-variance and even do the refactoring for you if you accept its suggestions. I don't know how well it works in the ambiguous/difficult situations, though (I'm assuming it just won't attempt a suggestion in those cases).

Answer (score 16):

Well, there are two questions here. Firstly, *could* the compiler always do so? Secondly, *should* it (if it can)?

For the first question, I'll defer to Eric Lippert, who made this comment when I brought exactly this issue up in the 2nd edition of C# in Depth:

> It's not clear to me that we reasonably could even if we wanted to. We can easily come up
>   with situations that require expensive global analysis of all the interfaces in a program
>   to work out the variances, and we can easily come up with situations where either it's
>   `<in T, out U>` or `<out T, in U>` and no way to decide between them. With both bad 
>   performance and ambiguous cases it's an unlikely feature.

(I hope Eric doesn't mind me quoting this verbatim; he's previously been very good about sharing such insights, so I'm going by past form :)

On the other hand, I suspect there are still cases where it *can* be inferred with no ambiguity, so the second point is still relevant...

I don't think it should be automatic even where the compiler can unambiguously know that it's valid in just one way. While expanding an interface is always a breaking change to some extent, it's generally not if you're the only one implementing it. However, if people are relying on your interface to be variant, you may not be *able* to add methods to it without breaking clients... even if they're just callers, not implementers. The methods you add may change a previously-covariant interface to become invariant, at which point you break any callers who are trying to use it covariantly.

Basically, I think it's fine to require this to be explicit - it's a design decision you should be making consciously, rather than just accidentally ending up with covariance/contravariance without having thought about it.

Comment: If making generic types covariance/contravariance can lead to "breaking clients" then why did .NET creators replace their major generic interfaces to co/contravariant counterparts in .NET 4.0?

Comment: @Koistya: It's not that way round: it's the other way round. If it's been inferred to be covariant, but then you add a method which makes it *invariant*, then any clients which are using the covariance will be screwed. I'll edit to explain this.

Comment: @Koistya: Making invariant types into variant types is in fact a breaking change; we decided that the benefit of the change was worth the pain of the break. See my article on that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/02/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-nine-breaking-changes.aspx - However, Jon correctly notes that the kind of break he is talking about is that *editing an interface can change its legal variance annotations unexpectedly*. We would therefore like to make those annotations explicit, rather than deducing them.

Comment: @Jon: Re "I hope Eric doesn't mind..." - quote away my friend. I trust you to quote me in context. :-)

Comment: Can you think of any example where client relying on a generic interface's type to be invariant. If changing generic from invariant to variant is a breaking change what could be a percent of code which will be affected by this change? In other words how many developers from a million will complain about it? :)

Comment: @Koistya Navin: If code is allowed to determine that an object cannot be cast to a given type, it's possible to write code which will be broken if a formerly impermissible cast becomes permissible.  Likewise if code is allowed to determine that a class does not support some method, it's possible to write code which will be broken if a method is added to a class which formerly lacked it.

Comment: @supercat Interesting, could you give example code for this?

Comment: @user42723: As a trivial contrived example with pseudo-code syntax for member availability: `if (someObject has someMethod) doSomethingEvil(); else doSomethingGood();`.  Such code will do something good unless or until `someObject`' type has `someMethod` added to it, whereupon it will start doing something evil instead.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336029.aspx) explains that there are situations that the compiler cannot infer and so it provides you with the explicit syntax:

```
interface IReadWriteBase<T>
{
    IReadWrite<T> ReadWrite();
}

interface IReadWrite<T> : IReadWriteBase<T>
{

}
```

What do you infer here `in` or `out`, both work?

Comment: Compiler could apply `out` keyword here by default to the base interface based on usage and the same for the derived interface based on parent T

Comment: Yep, you can set both manually but from compiler point of view, it could set T be covariant by default in your example. Yes or No?

Comment: Yes, but if the compiler took this decision and I wanted to use `in`, in this case we have a conflict which can be resolved only by being explicit.

Comment: If you want to specify `in` then compiler will just keep it as you specified without any attempt to infer this type and if you didn't specified `in`/`out` explicitly compiler will make it's own assumption.

Comment: I usually don't like the compiler to make assumptions on my behalf... if there's a possible ambiguity, the compiler should *never* make that kind of assumption. How would you know whether your interface is covariant or contravariant ?

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed. What makes this worse is that if *other* interfaces inherit from this one or have this one in the formal parameters or return types of their methods, then the analysis of *them* changes depending on whether this one is covariant or contravariant. Making that choice one way or the other has implications that are not local.